# Behaviour of a rocket's second stage after detachment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, estimation, rocket-science

For a school project I'm making a simulation of a falcon 9 rocket. I'm trying to make the simulation as realistic as possible, but there's one thing I don't really understand, and can't find the answer to on the internet.

Basically, say the rocket is rotating around an axis orthogonal to its orientation (I guess you'd call this pitch? I'm not really familiar with the terminology yet), and the second stage detaches. So far I thought you'd get the following behaviour:

The velocity of the second stage is equal to the velocity of the center of mass of the total rocket before detachment, plus the second stage's angular velocity before detachment:

$$vNew = v + omega * r$$

Where $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and $r$ the distance between the second stage's center of mass and the center of mass right before detachment. This doesn't take into account the centrifugal force though, how would I apply that in this scenario?

Also, what would the rotational speed of the second stage be? When looking at a pendulum, I'd say it would stay the same, since all points on a pendulum rotate at the same speed. Is that correct? It doesn't 'feel' right to me.

Comment: Once the second stage detaches, its angular momentum can't change (if it fires its engine, have to include the expelled mass in the calculation of this angular momentum).  However, in general angular momentum and angular velocity for an odd-shaped object are not proportional or even parallel.  So while the rotational speed of the second stage immediately after separation is the same as it was immediately before (same as for the combined stages) it may change, depending on the orientation of the angular velocity vector relative to the inertia tensor.

Comment: I'd bet that the tangential velocity of rotation at separation is small compared to the effects of turbulent buffering: they don't spin these things like whiligigs. This is something that you ignore at the level of your simulation because it is washed out by other effects you are also ignoring.